# How to get data from intervals in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

In one cell I have postcode intervals that looks like "50-54". Now I want to breakdown this interval into separate numbers in different rows so that row 1 has 50, row 2 has 51 and so on.

I also need to make sure that the data in other columns for the interval is also copied for the separate numbers. By this I mean that 53 should have same columns and data as the overall interval "50-54".

Can someone please help me with this. Thanks

[image: Example Data]

I tried splitting it with delimiter first and thinking of some other way but that didn't work.

Comment: Please include markdown sample data, expected results and your own attempt. Please also, make sure you are not forgetting any other type of data. Usually with this format you would see stuff like `1,5,6-10,11` as well.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I have added the sample and expected results. Indeed you are correct, the data was earlier in the format like 1,5,6-10,11 but then I was able to split that through delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated* Based on the new information, we'll check if the cell has a "-" character, then if it does we'll expand the section. Unfortunately since you want to copy the values for the intervals (essentially writing new values for the data), we're going to need to use VBA.

```
Public Sub intervalExpand()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim lastRow As Long, rowNum As Long
    Dim from As Variant, rate As Variant
    
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    rowNum = 3 'The row where your pasted data starts
    
    For Each cell In ws.Range("B" & rowNum & ":B" & lastRow)
        from = cell.Offset(0, -1)
        rate = cell.Offset(0, 1)
        'Goes to the column before then after to get the from/rate values
        If InStr(1, cell, "-") > 0 Then
            Dim length As Integer, startNum As Integer
            'Get the start of the range and the length of the range
            startNum = CInt(Split(cell.Value, "-")(0))
            length = -Evaluate(cell.Value)
            
            For i = 0 To length
                ws.Cells(rowNum + i, 6).Value = startNum + i
                ws.Cells(rowNum + i, 5).Value = from
                ws.Cells(rowNum + i, 7).Value = rate
            Next i
            rowNum = rowNum + length + 1
        Else
            ws.Cells(rowNum, 6).Value = cell.Value
            ws.Cells(rowNum, 5).Value = from
            ws.Cells(rowNum, 7).Value = rate
            rowNum = rowNum + 1
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

The Macro just checks if the To column (in "B") has a - in each cell, if so it will expand this and retain the original From and Rate values as well. Here is the output I got from a quick test:

[image]

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your comment! For more clarity I have added an image that should help. Can I still use your solution to get the results that I expect? Thanks

Comment: Oh that makes it much clearer. No my solution interpreted your needs very differently, so it won't work. Let me make some edits

Answer (score 1):

A little verbose, but working as desired:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=LET(d,"-",x,A3:C9,REDUCE(A2:C2,SEQUENCE(ROWS(x)),LAMBDA(y,z,LET(i,INDEX(x,z,0),q,INDEX(i,2),s,--TEXTBEFORE(q&d,d),VSTACK(y,IF({1,0,0},INDEX(i,1),IF({1,1,0},IF({1,0},,SEQUENCE(TEXTAFTER(d&q,d,-1)-s+1,,s)),INDEX(i,3))))))))
```

Comment: Thank you for this. When I add the formula it gives me an error saying "the first argument in LET function should be a valid name". Can you help me on how I can resolve that?

Comment: Do you have ms365? Also, what is the correct delimiter in your Excel between arguments? Might be a semicolon? @Dante2034

Comment: Yes, I have ms365 and yes in formulas the arguments are separated by a semicolon. Is that what you asked?

Comment: Yes, maybe you haven't properly translated this formula? @Dante2034. Note that the comma's inside the `{1,1,0}` parts should be translated by a backslash most likely.

Comment: =LET(d;"-";x;A3:C9;REDUCE(A2:C2;SEQUENCE(ROWS(x));LAMBDA(y;z;LET(i;INDEX(x;z;0);q;INDEX(i;2);s;--TEXTBEFORE(q&d;d);VSTACK(y;IF({1;0;0};INDEX(i;1);IF({1;1;0};IF({1;0};;SEQUENCE(TEXTAFTER(d&q;d;-1)-s+1;;s));INDEX(i;3)))))))

Comment: Hi JvdV, I made the changes in the formula^. It works but there are some issues. Can you please let me know how can I correct the same? Thanks